# Ruby: how can I find all class method of module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

For example I have this code:

```
module ExampleModule
  def self.module_method
  end

  def normal_method
  end
end
```

If I try to call  `ExampleModule.instance_methods` and I can see only `normal_method`. I have searched also in `singleton_class` but looks like Ruby doesn't put class method inside `singleton class`:

```
ExampleModule.singleton_class.each do |method|
  print method
end
```

How can see `self.module_method` (and only this method, not other parent method of module ExampleModule).

Thanks

Comment: `ExampleModule.methods`

Comment: I wouldn't call this "metaprogramming". It's just the use of plain old `send`.

Comment: @trueinViso but it will show all methods. I just want to show only custom defined method in this module.

Comment: @CarySwoveland My fault.I'm just trying to do some metaprogramming. and this is only a small step to that. I will edit my question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland But I don't see how to use `send` in this situation. Can you tell me more. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to post that comment on your other recent question, where `send` is used (but I don't regard this question as metaprogramming either ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ExampleModule.methods(false)
  #=> [:module_method] 
ExampleModule.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:module_method]
ExampleModule.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:normal_method]
```